# Creating a windows lib in C++ on Windows7 using Windows10SDK

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-10-universal, storagefolder

I'm a little rusty when it comes to making .lib and .DLLs so please pardon my ignorance on some of the details but here is my question.

I'm making a (Universal Windows) lib in C++ using Visual Studio and Windows 7. The lib has simple convenience functions for doing things like sub-string, index of, etc.

One of these functions requires that I use the Windows 10 SDK, specifically:

```
StorageFolder* appFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

create_task(appFolder->GetFilesAsync()).then([=](IVectorView<StorageFile*>* filesInFolder) 
{
    //Iterate over the results and print the list of files
    // to the visual studio output window
    for (auto it = filesInFolder->First(); it->HasCurrent; it->MoveNext())
    {
        StorageFile* file = it->Current;
        String* output = file->Name + "\n";
        OutputDebugString(output->Begin());
    }
});
```

My question is, how do I do make this lib as compatable as possible and more importantly how do I get it to work? I understand I'm using Windows7 and these classes are only available in Windows10 so I would assume I would install the Windows10 SDK and include it in my lib project but it still cant find StorageFolder. Is the only option for me to move into Windows10? Can my lib still work if the user is using it on Windows7?

Comment: These APIs will never work on Windows 7. The API in question you're using works only in Windows Store applications, which by definition cannot run on Windows 7. 
Now, the real question is why do you want to use this API on Windows 7? What do you expect it will do outside of installed app container context?

Comment: I guess the reason I want to use this on windows 7 is for backwards compatibility. Unless perhaps it makes sense to just move on from windows 7 since it will be phased out. I didn't want to limit the lib to only being used on windows 10 and above, I wanted to try to make it work also on windows 7 and include the windows 10 sdk with it.

Comment: You clearly can not use a function that doesn't exist on Windows 7 just by including a reference to it in your code. If the function doesn't exist on the OS version, it's not available for use on that OS version. (This seems like basic common sense, doesn't it?) Backward-compatibility means that your newer version still works for older versions, not that you can add future functionality that doesn't exist to it.

Comment: Let me ask a different question: are you making a library for Windows Store applications or for traditional Windows desktop applications?

Comment: @Ken White I agree it sounds like common sense but I was thinking there was a way to somehow package that module.

This is for traditional windows desktop applications. When I created the lib project, it was by default Universal Windows so I assume this is the new and correct way to create libs.

Comment: Is there a way to set my lib to be a traditional lib and not a Univeral Windows Lib? I guess that's the root of my issue.

Comment: If the function is not available on the OS, there's no way to *package it*. If that were possible, MS would have added it to the earlier version in a service pack and documented it as being available. If you read the MSDN documentation for a function and it says *Requires this OS version*, that means it **requires that OS version**.

Comment: @KenWhite Fair Enough

Comment: "It was by default Universal Windows so I assume this is the new and correct way to create libs" - it is NOT the correct way to create libs for desktop applications. You need to create "Win32" type project.

Comment: @Sunius Thanks, I'll change it now.

Answer (score 0):

This API that you use won't work on windows 7 or vista or any earlier.
But a suggestion is to make your code reusable as much as possible and use it to make the Universal Windows App and the Windows 7 program.

actually any New API for windows 10 won't work on windows 7 ("Microsoft's evil plan to make developers and people switch to windows 10")
i hope you find the solution.
my regards.